# Can mozswing download file

Tags: java, mozilla, xpcom, xulrunner

I'm trying to distribute a Java Browser build upon MozSwing. When I click on a download link in the HTML page I'm surfing, application freezes. Do you have any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of initialization of the C code in the 2.0 release [click here](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/mozswing/2008-August/000197.html) to get details.